# How to execute Cloud Run containers into an Airflow DAG?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to run a container with Cloud Run as a task of an Airflow's DAG.

Seems that there are no things like a CloudRunOperator or similar and I can't find anything on documentations (either Cloud Run and Airflow one).

Have someone ever dealt with this problem?
If yes, how can I run a container with Cloud Run and handle xcom?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK when a container is deployed to Cloud Run it automatically listens possible requests to be sent. See [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port) for reference.

Instead you can send a request to access the deployed container. You can do this by using the code below.

This DAG has three tasks `print_token`, `task_get_op` and `process_data`.

- `print_token` prints the identity token needed to authenticate the requests to your deployed Cloud Run container. I used "xcom_pull" get the output of "BashOperator" and assign the authentication token to `token` so this could be used to authenticate to HTTP request that you will perform.
- `task_get_op` performs a GET on the connection `cloud_run` (this just contains the Cloud Run endpoint) and defined headers `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token` for the authentication.
- `process_data` performs "xcom_pull" on "task_get_op" to get the output and print it using PythonOperator.

```
import datetime

import airflow
from airflow.operators import bash
from airflow.operators import python
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

with airflow.DAG(
        'composer_http_request',
        'catchup=False',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    print_token = bash.BashOperator(
        task_id='print_token', 
        bash_command='gcloud auth print-identity-token "--audiences=https://hello-world-fri824-ab.c.run.app"' # The end point of the deployed Cloud Run container
    ) 

    token = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='print_token') }}" # gets output from 'print_token' task

    task_get_op = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='get_op',
        method='GET',
        http_conn_id='cloud_run',
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token },
    )

    def process_data_from_http(**kwargs):
      ti = kwargs['ti']
      http_data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_op')
      print(http_data)

    process_data = python.PythonOperator(
      task_id='process_data_from_http',
      python_callable=process_data_from_http,
      provide_context=True
      )
    print_token >> task_get_op >> process_data
```

`cloud_run` connection:

[image]

Output (graph):

[image]

print_token logs:

[image]

task_get_op logs:

[image]

process_data logs (output from GET):
[image]

NOTE: I'm using Cloud Composer 1.17.7 and Airflow 2.0.2 and installed `apache-airflow-providers-http` to be able to use the [SimpleHttpOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/_api/airflow/providers/http/operators/http/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Ricco, very interesting solution! But this implies to having a container always up and running, waiting evenctually for a call for "do something".
I was searching for something like the KubernetesPodOperator that allows me to deploy my application even waiting for tearing up time!

Comment: If ever you are concerned with the cost of Cloud Run, based from [Cloud Run pricing](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing#billable-time) even when a container is deployed it won't incur charges, it will only start charging when a request is processed. I'm not very familiar with KubernetesPodOperator. You can try creating a PythonOperator to automate the deployment in Cloud Run, the downside of it is it will be a lot of work.